# Delete directories using find command or anything else

Tags: linux, shell-script, find, rm, delete

I am trying to write a command that will keep only the last 2 backups and delete the remaining directories.

```
directory path = /apps/
```

Below are the directories and here I would like to keep only

- `source`
- `source_2020-01-13`
- `source_2019-12-09`

directories and delete the old ones. This script will run across 100+ servers using cron.

Here problem is, in `find` command I wont be able to add `mtime` to delete old directories - why because backup directories timestamp will not be same on all servers. Basically the command/script should keep the last two backup directories that is with source_YYYY_MM_DD name and delete the remaining ones.

Can someone please assist?

Note : **Source_YYYY_MM_DD** are the backup directories.

```
drwx------ 11 root   root   4096 Jul 22  2019 source_2019-07-22
drwx------ 11 root   root   4096 Jul 29  2019 source_2019-07-29
drwx------ 11 root   root   4096 Aug  5  2019 source_2019-08-05
drwx------ 11 root   root   4096 Aug 14  2019 source_2019-08-14
drwx------ 11 root   root   4096 Oct 14  2019 source_2019-10-14
drwx------ 11 root   root   4096 Dec  9 03:59 source_2019-12-09
drwx------ 11 root   root   4096 Jan 13 05:20 source_2020-01-13
drwxr-x--- 12 root   root   4096 Apr 21 09:11 source
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -d1 /apps/source_20??-??-??/ | head -n -2 | xargs rm -rf
```

Whereby
`ls -d1 /apps/source_20??-??-??/` will list only matching directories in sorted order,
`head -n -2` will take out the last two entries and
`xargs rm -rf` will then delete the directories.

Comment: Thank you - This command is reliable and deleted the directories as i need

Answer (score 1):

```
find /apps/ -type d -not -name source -name "source*" -print | sort | head -n -2 | xargs rm -rfv
```

`find apps/ -type d -not -name source -name "source*" -print` will find all backup directories making sure the `source` is not picked up by the `find` command.

`sort` will sort, making sure the most recent ones comes last. This is not based on modification times, rather the directory name.

`head -n -2` gets all dirs expect the last 2 backup dirs.

`xargs rm -rfv` deletes the all the backup directories expect the last 2 filtered by the previous command.

*(Caution: If you directory names contain spaces, this command will not work. Always test first creating fake directories and trying this command.)*

Comment: Thank you!! Will give it a try and let you know the results

Comment: Hi - i have tried the command shared under a test directory but it deleted all the "source_"  backup directories and didn't deleted source directory alone.                                                      
                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                      
 find /apps/test/ -type d -not -name source -name "source*" -print | sort | head -n -2 | xargs rm -rfv

Comment: Can you please assist further?